# Detecting change point in a time series

Tags: time-series, arima, stationarity, seasonality, change-point

I'm dealing with time series from satellite imagery, where I have a sudden change (drop), that I can see from the plot, but I need a statistical test to detect it. I already checked for stationarity using Dickey-Fuller, and this test doesn't detect the change. 
Basically the time series has a first part with a certain average, and the second part with a lower average, and I need to detect where (when) the change occurs.
The time series also have seasonality.

Thanks for any pointers

Edit: this is a sample of the data, that may or may not have a change point: https://pastebin.com/bVSsxVtR

Comment: Is everything besides the average about the same before and after the drop?

Comment: Check Shiryaev-Robert and Cusum, as far as I know they are powerful method for change point detection.

Comment: Perhaps check out the `mcp` package ([website and docs here](https://lindeloev.github.io/mcp/)) in R which is one of the only packages to quantify uncertainty of the change point and to do more informed hypothesis testing.  If you include the data here, I'd be happy to write up an answer.

Comment: Thank you all for your valuable input! @JonasLindeløv thanks! I'm looking into it. However, so far it seems to me that it requires you to "force" it into a model, because you have to specify a model a priori. this means that it is forced to detect a change point also when it is not there or not significant. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this with `mcp`. First, let's get your data in an accessible format. The variable "days" is the number of days since the first record. I remove the NAs:

```
library(dplyr)
D = read.table("bVSsxVtR.txt") %>%
  rename(row = V1, date = V2, y = V3) %>%
  mutate(days = as.numeric(as.POSIXct(date) - as.POSIXct("2014-10-31")) / (24*3600)) %>%
  select(-row)

head(D)

  V1       date         y days
1  1 2014-10-31 -18.13354    0
2  2 2014-11-04 -17.71648    4
3  4 2014-11-07 -15.03215    7
4  5 2014-11-24 -15.66677   24
5  6 2014-12-01 -18.37760   31
6  8 2014-12-13 -16.23460   43
```

Now let's fit to the data a model *with* a change point and a model *without* a change point. We add an AR(1) to both, to capture some of the time-series autocorrelation, but you can choose the order to your liking and add an `ar(N)` term to segment two too, if the change involves a change in the AR coefficient(s). Note that the dates are not equally spaced so the AR is not accurate, though it may be good enough.

```
model = list(y ~ 1 + ar(1), ~ 1)
fit = mcp(model, D, par_x = "days")

model_null = list(y ~ 1 + ar(1))
fit_null = mcp(model_null, D, par_x = "days")
```

Here's `plot(fit) + plot(fit_null)`, i.e., the model that was forced to identify a change point and the one without. The posterior (blue distribution on the right-hand plot) shows that *if* there is a change point, its location is quite well defined:

[image]

Now for the critical part: we use leave-one-out cross-validation to compare the predictive performance of the two models.

```
fit$loo = loo(fit)
fit_null$loo = loo(fit_null)
loo::loo_compare(fit$loo, fit_null$loo)

       elpd_diff se_diff
model1  0.0       0.0   
model2 -4.4       3.3
```

The change point model is preferred, but only slightly (small `elpd_diff / elpd_se` ratio). You can read more about modeling time-series, model comparison, etc. on the [mcp website](http://lindeloev.github.io/mcp).

Comment: Thank you Jonas! This is brilliant!

Comment: @MargheritaDiLeo. Happy to hear! Please upvote and accept answer(s) that solves your problem. Or submit your own answer and accept it, if you found a better way. This way CrossValidated becomes a great repository of solutions to problems.

Comment: Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score. I casted my vote. Thanks again!