# Change point analysis for detecting changes prior to disease

Tags: change-point

Am looking for advice regarding the application of change point analysis to clinical data. There may also be a better method of analysis that I'm unaware of.

My data consists of assessments of individuals conducted over their lifespan, until they were diagnosed with a disease. The data is very noisy, e.g. participant A was assessed at age 20, 42, 64 and 80, and was diagnosed with disease age 82; participant B was assessed at age 50, 60 and 72, and diagnosed with disease at 94.

My goal is to detect at what point in the lifetime a change in the assessments is detectable (if at all). Is this possible with this type of data? I am thinking to align each participants diagnosis point, and then work backwards (so assessments are e.g. -5 years, -20 years, regardless of the age of diagnosis). Would I then combine all the data from all participants?

I hope I've explained adequately and would really appreciate any guidance! Thank you.

Comment: Sounds like a segmented survival model would be appropriate. Check out the `segmented` R package for `survival::Surv()` models.

Comment: @JonasLindeløv I will check that out, thank you! I'd actually also just found your reply here: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/427585/detecting-change-point-in-a-time-series?rq=1 -- could I use something like that approach, but 'backwards', so 0 is the diagnosis date?